# Could someone explain the underlying undirected graph of the directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATx6j.jpg

Why doesn't D have any loop in the underlying undirected graph whereas E has a loop?

Comment: It's a mistake.

Comment: Looks like there's an error in the example.  I agree that E should not have a loop and D should have one.

Comment: Yes I was also having confusion at this point